# Read Excel data (cell)

Tags: javascript, excel, asp-classic, jscript

I'm trying and trying and I just can't. Please I need to read/display a specific cell in my html just like another text. I'm using this:

```
function readData()
{
     var excel=new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); 
     var book=excel.Workbooks.open("http://142.116.39.71/Produ.xls");
     var sheet=book.Worksheets.Item(1); 
     /*var data=sheet.Cells(x,y).Value;
    var data=book.ActiveSheet.Cells("");
    return data();*/

 excel.quit();
 excel.application.quit();
 excel = null;
 book = null;
 sheet = null;
 CollectGarbage();
}

    value=readData("E,18"); 
    //var value=readData("E18", "E18"); 

   document.write("Value from Excel file is "+value);
```

BUT..... I have this: `Value from Excel file is undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not returning any value. Uncomment the code and correct the code to be `return data;` and not `return data();`

Answer (score 0):

and you're not passing by the arguments to the function readData(x,y) and you're not declaring variable "value"        `var value = readData("E","18");`

multiple syntax error

Comment: <script language="javascript">

 function readData(x,y)
{

 var excel=new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
 var book=excel.Workbooks.Open("http://Produccion.xls");
 var sheet=book.sheets.Item(1);
 var data=sheet.Cells(x,y);
 //var data=book.ActiveSheet.Cells("");
 return data();
 
 excel.quit();
 excel.application.quit();
 excel = null;
 book = null;
 sheet = null;
 data = null;
 CollectGarbage();

}
var value = 0;
 value = readData("E","18");      
      document.write("Value from Excel file is " + value);

</script>